# Kruskal-Wallis statistical power

Tags: nonparametric, statistical-power, kruskal-wallis-test

Given that the Kruskal-Wallis $H$-test has been computed, the epsilon-squared estimate of effect size can be calculated as
$$E_R^2=\frac{H}{(n^2 - 1)/(n+1)},$$
the number of the compared groups, the significance level, and the number of observations are known, how to compute the statistical power of this nonparametric test?

Comment: You seem to be trying to compute *post hoc* power (i.e. power based on an *estimate* of effect from observed data).  If so, you might like to try a site search for [*post hoc power*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=post+hoc+power), where you should find clear condemnation of the notion, in detail.

Comment: ... and in some cases, with references. To quote one of the answers you can find with such a search, post hoc power calculations are "*at best useless and are often misleading*". That pretty much sums it up -- "useless" is the best-case scenario.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful comment. It is pretty useless indeed!